# Rasterize Vector MBTiles - vector mbtiles to raster mbtiles?

Tags: mapbox, mbtiles

I have a mbtiles which is a vector format; when I opened this in QGIS, dont see any symbology associated, but with Maptiler I can see all styles correspondingly. But my problem, I need to rasterize or convert vector mbtiles to raster mbtiles?

I did tried using following github forum https://github.com/bjornreppen/rasterize-vector-tiles/issues/6 but no luck to get the exact result!

Styled mbtiles from MapTiler
[image]

Non-style mbtiles in QGIS
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Symbology you can see at MapTiler Cloud is just a basic one which simply set blue color on all features from water layer, set green on all features from landcover layer etc...
To have beautiful maps mbtiles are not enough as they store only data. You need to get the data styled. I would point you to MapTiler plugin in QGIS where you can simply add various maps (already styled vector tiles). You can install the plugin from QGIS/Plugins/Manage and installs plugins...